# when using vim-latex gq causes overhangs in captions

Tags: vim, latex, reformat

When I am editing a LaTeX file using `Vim-LaTeX` and want to reformat a section of text that is in a `\caption{}` I get overhangs or underhangs - I am not sure what to call them.  I first select the text in the caption then use "gq" to reformat it.  After reformatting the caption looks like:

```
    \caption{The problem is that when I reformat the text
         in a caption the text on each successive line
      begins further and further to the left until it begins 
   at the first space of the line.}
```

what I would hope the result would look like would be something like:

```
    \caption{The problem is that when I reformat the text
         in a caption the text on each successive line
         begins further and further to the left until it 
         begins at the first space of the line.}
```

I hope the formatting in this post remains true to what I typed in, but I tried to describe the problem in the first  example caption.  The second should be left justified.

Does anyone know what I need to do to fix this?  I am assuming that there is a setting that I need to change, but I have not been able to figure out what it is.

Answer (score 1):

The `gq` command formats based on `'formatexpr'` or `'formatprg'`. You can start by checking the values of these options with `:se fex?` and `:se fp?`.

From looking through the `vim-latex` plugin it never sets these options, so this is likely set by your other plugins or vimrc. You can find out exactly where an option is set by using `:verbose`.

Comment: first a late thanks, I would upvote but apparently neither `'formatexpr'` or `'formatprg'` are set in my setup, so that doesn't help - yet.  A follow-up question that might move this forward.  I have found that if the text is moved so that it isn't on the same line as either {}, then it formats properly - unfortunately I don't know how to clarify by providing a good  example here.  But if I change from `\caption{some text}` to `\caption{` - then I put, `"some text"` on a new line, then on yet another line I put `}`.  I can select the text and `gq` will properly format.